# Prove any symmetric and anti-symmetric matrix is an eigenvector for the given linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Prove that any symmetric or anti-symmetric matrix is an eigenvector for the given linear map L: M_n(R) -> M_n(R) M-> 2M - 3(M)ˆtr

My attempt: 
Let a be an eigenvalue of M. Let x be an eigenvector corresponding to a. Hence we have M.x = a.x
M = Mˆtr (symmetric matrix)
M = -Mˆtr (antisymmetric matrix)

1) Proof for symmetric matrix. We replace M.x=a.x with the linear map's outpit 2M-3(M)ˆtr
[2M-3(M)ˆtr].x - a.x = 0
Since M = Mˆtr => x[2(M)ˆtr-3M - a] = 0 => x(-M-a) = 0 => This is what I get at the end: -M.x = a.x

I am not sure how to approach this task.

Comment: You've been around for two months. Haven't you noticed yet that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Start with a symmetric $M\ne 0$ and compute $L(M)$. This is $L(M) = 2M-3M'=2M-3M=-M=(-1)\cdot M$. This means $(-1)$ is an eigenvalue for $L$, and the eigenvector is $M$. Try to understand the "new level". (Eigenvalues of $M$ have nothing to do with the problem.)